# How to change the position of the X axis in the chart

Tags: c#, graph, charts, axis

How to change the position of the X axis in the chart, making it the top? I show example on the image

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There's no way for us to tell from your question how you made that example chart. Please [edit] your question to show some code you used to generate it.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the position of an `Axis` is usually done by setting the `Crossing` property to some value on the other, perpendicular `Axis`:

```
ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
ca.AxisX.Crossing = 2500;
```

But in your case you can simply **enable** the 'secondary' axis `AxisX2`:

```
ca.AxisX2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
```

Probably you want to disable the regular x-axis:

```
ca.AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
```

Of course you will have to apply all sorts of stylings and settings to the new, secondary axis!